# backbone.js app jquery ajaxsetup not always working when switching views

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js and I need to show the login view every time 403 and 401 errors are returned.
I've tried the following, but it seems like it stops listening to error after the first time ajaxSetup 'is used':

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    app.loadTemplates(['ShellView','HomeView','LoginView'],
        function() { //callback function after template loading
            app.router = new app.Router();
            Backbone.history.start();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                statusCode: {
                    401: function(){
                        //unauthorized, redirect to login page
                        app.router.login();
                    },
                    403: function(){
                        //access denied
                        app.router.login();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    );
});
```

how should I be implementing $.ajaxSetup to show my login view every time - not just once - when 401 and 403 errors are returned?

thank you

Comment: ajaxSetup() is called every time AJAX is used. Are you calling AJAX each time that you expect 401 and 403 errors? Are you watching the console while this occurs?

Comment: Does "app.router.login()" go to a full refresh of the page? or is your login page just another routed page in the SPA?

Comment: thanks for the help guys, I just posted an answer to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

The problem wasn't ajaxSetup. The problem was the switching between views without executing `view.remove()` for the view I was walking away from

for more information about how to switch views the right way using backbone, read this tutorial:
http://mikeygee.com/blog/backbone.html